# What exactly is an IoT Definition Engine?

Tags: communication, protocols, system-architecture

[image: Credits : simplilearn Youtube Channel]

So , i was watching an IoT primer video on YT, which i found to be helpful and moderately detailed

In the picture shown, they were showing the **IoT Reference Architecture** ( which i believe to be the IoT equivalent of the **OSI Reference Architecture** - please correct me if i am wrong )

in this particular timeframe of the video, the narrator says that "the combination of these two layers, IoT Devices' Layer and the IoT Gateway Layer, form the **definition engine** and set the rules for Data Aggregation"

My Question : why exactly is it called the Definition Engine ? and what purpose does it serve ?

Comment: OSI/ISO is a standards organisation, which produces standards with clear definitions. IoT is just marketing-speak and everyone have their own definition of whatever they want to define. There are no “IoT standards” beyond those of the technologies used by IoT devices (e.g. LoRaWAN, Zigbee, Bluetooth, WiFi, MQTT, etc.). So if that video defines an “IoT reference architecture”, that’s their own definition, there’s nothing official or universally recognised about it.

Comment: @jcaron this is a very unsettling predicament .. because if i am comprehending you correctly, then; apart from the messaging protocols ( MQTT / CoAP ) and communication protocols ( WiFi, Zigbee, LoraWAN etc ) , there are no set standards for IoT ? can you explain then, that how does the IoT ecosystem operate/exist in a systematic or at least in a standardized manner when IoT solutions, especially those of large scale / industrial focus, are being developed and adopted  ?

Comment: It doesn’t. It’s a myriad of different ecosystems, some using common standards, some not, or standards at some level and some not. It’s not like you can connect any IoT sensor to any IoT network, gateway, or server. Whenever you set up a system you need to find the right combination of devices, protocols, servers, networks, etc. to achieve your goal, depending on your requirements (including number of devices, distances, latency and bandwidth, energy, cost…).

Comment: I agree with jcaron's thoughts above that there's not really a standardization (beyond perhaps, supporting IP if you have to be on the internet). There have been proposed standards, but no widespread adoption of those. In that specific video, they were talking about those layers making a certain set of data available from the real world, into the rest of the processing systems of the cloud. From a cloud engineer's perspective, everything below the event processing engine can be put in a box called "data access layer". "Layer" may have been better than "Engine" there.

Comment: @jcaron I think your comments could be a quality answer.